# Which WM is sent where TAB key or Enter key is pressed?

Tags: windows-messages

I need the WM that is sent when TAB or Enter key is pressed.
Inspecting this list ( I don't know if this is the complete list of WM ) :
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html
I have tried several WM like :

```
WM_CHAR
WM_KEYDOWN
```

But none of this take care about TAB and Enter.
Is there any WM that has to do with these keys ?
Thank you !

**Updated:**
This is the code that I use :

```
Class NW
    Inherits NativeWindow
    Public Sub New(hwnd As IntPtr)
        AssignHandle(hwnd)
    End Sub

    Const WM_CHAR As Integer = &H102

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_CHAR Then
            Return
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End class
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're *able* to capture these keys, it *should* be `WM_CHAR` since they're both just characters off the keyboard.

But I suspect what you're experiencing is the fact that whatever control you're in is trapping these keys and interpreting them itself, the <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate to the next control and the <kbd>enter</kbd> to select the default action.

Since `WM_CHAR` messages are constructed in `TranslateMessage()` in response to `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, it would allow interception at that level and you may never even *see* the `WM_CHAR` messages.

---

To actually see in detail what messages are being sent to your Windows procedure so you can figure out what's going on, you can use [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460760.aspx), available from the `TOOLS` menu, at least in VS2013.

Comment: Thank you ! This is the code that I use : Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
            If m.Msg = WM_CHAR Then
                Return
            End If. .
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Sub
   But doesn't work for Enter and TAB

Comment: Sorry , I didn't find the Spy++ inside my Visual studio. But with your suggestions are you telling that the message that is sent in such case is unknown or change every time and depend by the case ?

Comment: Alex, it depends on the control itself. Classic example is a text control. When in one-line 'mode' it will pass on ENTER to elsewhere whereas a multiline control will process it itself. So it's not random but depends on the various different message pumps. Spy++ will tell you exactly what's happening re messages.

Comment: Yes  but  it doesn't matter how the key is processed. I just want to catch the message when this key is pressed. strange that doesn't exist a default unique message that I sent when these 2 keys are pressed.

Comment: @alex, what I'm saying is that the message you'll get depends on the control you're in. TAB and ENTER are examples of keys that may be handled specially by different controls. You may never _see_ a WM_CHAR for them because the WM_KEYDOWN may be being intercepted before TranslateMessage() has a chance to change it into a WM_CHAR. If you want to know what's actually happening rather than just guessing, you need something like Spy++.

Comment: Ok , but I think this problem may be resolved in another way. Is there a message that is sent when a control get focus ? and if we can catch this message in my code , how to make loose the focus immediately using message.Result= ??? something ? If I can do this , the Tab and enter keys will not have effect.

Comment: @alex, what you need to do depends on what you're trying to achieve, which isn't really detailed in the question. You've stated how you want to do something but it may be better to step back and tell us the actual use case for detecting these keys.